Vuetify make stepper scroll
I am using vuetify stepper. I have 14 steps which would be too large to fit in, so I decided to wrap it within a div and force it's width to make sure it overflows in the x direction. I also created a wrapper for that to let it scroll. But so far I cannot make that scroll.
I should mention that this stepper is used within a expansion-panel.
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue';

// Hardcoded steps
const steps = [
  { id: "X", title: "1", complete: false, icon: "mdi-domain" },
  { id: "Y", title: "2", complete: false, icon: "mdi-file-tree" },
  { id: "Z", title: "3", complete: false, icon: "mdi-database-cog" },
  { id: "H", title: "4", complete: false, icon: "mdi-tune" },
  { id: "M", title: "5", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "6", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "7", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "8", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "9", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "10", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "11", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "12", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "13", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
  { id: "M", title: "14", icon: "mdi-file-check-outline" },
];

// Reactive variables
const currentStep = ref(1);
const stage = ref('');

// Function to check if a value is present (dummy function)
const hasValue = (value) => !!value;

// Update the complete property based on your logic (dummy logic for example purposes)
steps.forEach(step => {
  step.complete = hasValue(step.id); // Example logic, replace with your actual logic
});
</script>

<template>
  <div id="stepper-wrapper">
  <div id="stepper">
  <v-stepper 
    v-model="currentStep" 
    alt-labels
    elevation="0" 
    :border="false" 
    density="compact"
  >
    <v-stepper-header>
      <template v-for="(step, index) in steps" :key="step.id">
        <v-stepper-item 
          :value="index" 
          :rules="step.rules" 
          :color="index < 5 ? 'green' : (index === 5 ? 'red' : 'grey')"
          editable
          @click="stage='form'"
          :ripple="false"
        >
          <template v-slot:title>
            {{ step.title }}
          </template>
          <template v-slot:subtitle v-if="step.subtitle">
            {{ step.subtitle }}
          </template>
          <template v-slot:icon>
            {{ index + 1 }}
          </template>
        </v-stepper-item>
        <v-divider v-if="index !== steps.length - 1" :key="'divider-' + step.id" />
      </template>
    </v-stepper-header>
  </v-stepper>
  </div>
</div>
</template>

<style scoped>
#stepper-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto; 
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

#stepper {
  display: block;
  background-color: teal;
  min-width: 100vw;
  overflow-x: auto; 
  padding: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap; 
}
</style>

This is what I see:
Result
I tried several configurations of wrapper components.

P.S: Here is the link to the reproducible example. While when I zoom in I can see the scroll in the white area, what I wanted to do is to make these icons also so large so that at a view at any time there are 3-4 visible steps, so that way scrolling makes more sense and allows for larger content in the steps.
For clarity, this is the desired component:


Can you create a reproducible example, as v-stepper component scroll in x -direction when used directly.

Hi @YashMaheshwari
I just changed my code to my whole Step component. What I am thinking of is having a large stepper (14 steps), so it would be very small in one screen width (by default stepper fits all steps in its parent component). I want to increase the parent component x direction and make it overflow so that steps are larger but one can scroll in the x direction.
Please let me know if I should provide more information.

There are many places where you can reproduce the problem, so please do so.

@imhvost Do you mean online platforms for showing my current component in an interactive way online?
Thanks.

@Hossein I have tried this component with 14+ steps but it automatically adds scrolling, that's why It would be good if you will create a reproducible example. Like a code sandbox link, or jsFiddle, or codepen or vue playground.

@YashMaheshwari Thanks. I reproduced it and added an addenum to my post. I need to also increase the step size to a larger one (a larger rectangle for example) so that scrolling makes more sense.  Thanks.
